# Is there anyway to return particular elements from JFrame?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

Lets imagine that JFrame containes 9 JTextFields like so:

```
public static JFrame generateFrame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    JTextField[]textFields = new JTextField[9];
    for(int i=0; i<9;i++){
        textFields[i]= new JTextField(1);
        textFields[i].setFont(new Font("Sans-serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        panel.add(textFields[i]);
    }

    c.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,300);

    return frame;
}
```

So I assign this returned JFrame to variable in main method like so:

```
    public static void main(String []args){
    JFrame gameFrame = generateFrame(); 
}
```

Is there anyway to extract all the textfields from "gameFrame" object? Something like docyment.getElementByTagName("element") equivalent in DOM?

Comment: there isn't implemented this abstraction, see [putClientProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to take the reference of contentpane as you have added your JPanel to contentpane then from JPanel you can get your fields.

```
JFrame gameFrame = generateFrame();
JPanel panel = (JPanel) gameFrame.getContentPane().getComponent(0);

Component[] comp = panel.getComponents();

for (Component c : comp) {
    JTextField field = (JTextField) c;
    System.out.println("value   :   " + field.getText());
}
```

Comment: +1 for ContentPane only, maybe not important in this case, but good catch

Answer (score 3):

Try following.

```
Component[] components = gameFrame.getComponents();
 for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
  if (components[i] instanceof JTextField) {
     //DO what you want with the text field here 
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, I see how this could work. But will just wait to see if there is any DOM like solution, if not i'll just accept yours. You get an upvote anyway :)

Comment: please to add `if (components[i] instanceof JTextField)` for better and nice answer

Comment: Added your suggestion @ mKorbel.

Comment: I don't think so this solution will work for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If the components are all on a single panel you can use the getComponents() method of the panel as already suggested.

If you have components on multiple panels then you need to use recursion to get all the component. In this case you may find Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class handy.